# Using getClass().getName() in toString() methods

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have the following classes defined:

```
class BaseClass {
    public String toString()
    {
        return "I am a: " + getClass().getName();
    }
}

class DerivedClass {
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

In my main() function I have the following code:

```
BaseClass b = new BaseClass();
DerivedClass d = new DerivedClass();

System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(d);  // not sure why/how this works!
```

As expected, I do get the correct run-time class types when this code runs:

```
I am a: BaseClass
I am a: DerivedClass
```

My question is, how exactly does the call to `toString()` in my DerivedClass work?  In my DerivedClass override of `toString()`, I'm making a call to `super.toString()` which seems like it should actually return "I am a: BaseClass" because we're calling `toString()` on the parent class.

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that my base class `toString()` utilizes `getClass().getName()`, so that when I call it through a subclass object, Java must be detecting my actual object type - but I don't know how it knows to do that...

Sorry if this sounds like a noob question, but I'm still wrapping my head around the concept of polymorphism.  If anyone could explain why this works the way it does, I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: `getClass().getName()` will return the **runtime** type.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--

Comment: When you call an instance method, there is an object called `this` implicitly passed into it. In this case, `this` is an instance of `DerivedClass`. So calling `this.getClass()` (which is what you are calling) returns the class for `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 2):

`getClass()` is a polymorphic method. It returns the actual concrete class of the object on which it is called. Since `d` id of type `DerivedClass`, its `getClass()` method returns `DerivedClass.class`.

You would get the result you expect if the method implementation was

```
return "I am a: " + BaseClass.class.getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Someone else pointed out (and I forgot about) the "this" parameter that was also being sent into the call to super.toString(), so I can see now that getClass() is actually being called on a DerivedClass object, via the "this" parameter.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your classes looked like this:

```
class BaseClass {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "I am a: " + getClass().getName();
    }

    public Class<?> getClass() {
        return BaseClass.class;
    }
}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public Class<?> getClass() {
        return DerivedClass.class;
    }
}
```

Because of the way overriding works, `getClass()` will always return `DerivedClass.class` when invoked on an instance of `DerivedClass`, even when called from the superclass `BaseClass`. Calling `super.toString()` doesn't change that, and is in fact entirely unnecessary, since the superclass implementation is inherited by default.

Note that this is just a demonstration of what you can expect when calling `getClass()`. In real life, `getClass()` is actually a `final native` method. Overriding it is not possible or necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - I was getting tripped up by the call to super.toString() in my DerivedClass' toString() method.  I wasn't sure how Java knew to (correctly) print the DerivedClass since it was being called from the base class toString().  But I also forgot about the "this" parameter that identified the correct object to call the toString() method on.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is:

> System.out.println(d);  // not sure why/how this works!

And it is a good question! After all, you are passing the `println` method a reference, `d`, to an instance of `DerivedClass`. Why would that result in actually calling a method that is named `toString()`?

The answer to this question lies in the Javadoc for the appropriate `println` method. The compiler (`javac`) correctly compiles your code to say that you are interested in calling the `println` method that takes in an `Object`. Note that println is an *overloaded* method and compiler must resolve the right method based on passed argument(s). In this case, the method resolves to [println(Object x)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) which states:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

Then you visit the `String.valueOf()` method and see:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Bingo! That closes the first loop, either the `BaseClass`'s `toString()` is called, or `DerivedClass`'s.

The actual reason why the `d`'s `getClass()` is called has to do with the value of the `this` reference. As you perhaps know, every instance method in Java (like the `toString()` one) receives an invisible parameter called the `this` reference in addition to the arguments that are declared. In this particular case, since the `this` reference points to `d`, all the methods are invoked on that reference. The *class* of `d` is clearly `DerivedClass`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response!  So in other words, the call to super.toString() will invoke the toString() method in my superclass (which in my example is BaseClass.toString())...I forgot about the "this" parameter.  I wasn't sure why getClass().getName() resulted in printing "DerivedClass" but considering the "this" parameter, that makes more sense.  Thanks again!

Comment: Right. `d.toString()` calls `DerivedClass toString()` which calls the `getClass()` on `d` because `this` points to `d` at that point. And obviously, `d.getClass()` should return a reference to the _class object_ that represents `DerivedClass`.